# Why does the listings package not highlight operators correctly?

Tags: listings

I am typing some notes about the programming language R.
Unfortunately, the `listings` package seems to recognize some math operators,
but not others.
For instance, in the example below,
`*` and `%%` are typeset in a different color as desired,
but `%/%` and `+` and `-` and `^` are not typeset in a different color.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
language=R,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
backgroundcolor=\color{white!95!black},
commentstyle=\color{green},
keepspaces=true,
keywordstyle=\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

You can use R as a simple calculator:
\begin{lstlisting}
> # The hash symbol '#' will comment out the rest of the line
> 2 + 3
[1] 5
> 7 - 3
[1] 4
> 4 * 5
[1] 20
> 3^4          # Exponentiation
[1] 81
> 43 %% 10     # Modulo operator
[1] 3
> 43 / 10      # Floating point division
[1] 4.3
> 43 %/% 10    # Integer division
[1] 4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get an output where all of the math operators are typeset in blue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the `R` language, `listings` defines:

```
otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_,/},
```

so neither `+` nor `-` nor `^` are listed, they have to be added.

Regarding `%/%` it seems that only adding `\%` before it in `otherkeywords` let it work as expected.

In other words, adding:

```
otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,+,-,^,\%,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_,/},
```

to your `\lstset` does what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
language=R,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
backgroundcolor=\color{white!95!black},
commentstyle=\color{green},
keepspaces=true,
otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,+,-,^,\%,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_,/},
keywordstyle=\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

You can use R as a simple calculator:
\begin{lstlisting}
> # The hash symbol '#' will comment out the rest of the line
> 2 + 3
[1] 5
> 7 - 3
[1] 4
> 4 * 5
[1] 20
> 3^4          # Exponentiation
[1] 81
> 43 %% 10     # Modulo operator
[1] 3
> 43 / 10      # Floating point division
[1] 4.3
> 43 %/% 10    # Integer division
[1] 4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but you forgot a small detail of adding in `^` in the `otherkeywords`. :-)

Comment: @ILiketoCode You are right, I didn't noticed it. Added it in the answer.